# Eager loading in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying eagerloading in elastic search. 
I have indexing as follows-

```
{"index":{"_index":"appname-ticketing","_type":"BLR"}}
```

My mapping is as follows-

```
    {
  "appname-ticketing" : {
    "mappings" : {
    "BLR" : {
       "AppName" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        },
    "ABC" : {
       "AppName" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

So index is appname-ticketing and type is BLR.
For the field, `AppName`, I want to enable eager loading.
This is what I am doing-

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/appname-ticketing/BLR/_mapping/AppName -d"
{
  \"tags\": {
    \"type\": \"string\", \"index\" : \"not_analyzed\",
    \"fielddata\": {
      \"loading\" : \"eager\" 
    }
  }
}"
```

But I am getting the following error-

```
No handler found for uri [/appname-ticketing/BLR/_mapping/AppName] and method [PUT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like this instead:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/appname-ticketing/BLR/_mapping -d '{
  "properties": {
    "AppName": {
      "type": "string", 
      "index" : "not_analyzed",
      "fielddata": {
        "loading" : "eager" 
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear. Please have a look at my update in the question for the mappings I had used. After trying your fix I am getting the following error- `Mapper for [AppName] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [AppName] is used by multiple types.`

Comment: Yes, you cannot have two fields with the same name but different settings in two different mapping types within a single index. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#merging-conflicts)

Answer (score 1):

I think adding the update_all_types parameter updates the text field in BLR and ABC and all other types:

This happens because the mappings are essentially flattened into a single, global schema for the entire index. And that’s why two types cannot define conflicting fields.[see this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/mapping.html)

Lucene wouldn’t know what to do when the mappings are flattened together hence the error.

So you will need to do something like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/appname-ticketing/_mapping/BLR/?update_all_type -d '{
  "properties": {
    "AppName": {
      "type": "string", 
      "index" : "not_analyzed",
      "fielddata": {
        "loading" : "eager" 
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

for any further reference you can have a look at the 
[this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#merging-conflicts)

Comment: kudos mentioning the `update_all_type` parameter, good call! +1